# Область видимости массива внутри класса PHP

Tags: php, ооп, область-видимости

Имеется класс, в нём функция `doConstruct`, в ней массив `pageInfo`
Нужно взять данные из этого массива в функцию `doPhotoConstruct`. Как это сделать? Если объявлять массив как `static` - не пашет. Пока что работает только через `$GLOBALS[]`, но мне **не нужна** глобальная переменная. Передавать в качестве аргумента тоже **не вариант**, т.к. эта функция вызывается не в этом файле.

```php
class PageProfile extends AbstractForm{


    /**
     * @event construct 
     */
    function doConstruct(UXEvent $e = null)
    {    

        // Отправляем запрос    
        $url = $GLOBALS['rknSuck'] . "/api/v23/method/profile.get "; # адрес сервера
        $post_data = array ( # то что уходит на сервер
            "accountId" => $GLOBALS['accountId'],
            "accessToken" => $GLOBALS['accessToken'],
            "profileId" => $GLOBALS['accountId'],
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        $outputJS = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $output = json_decode($outputJS, true);

       $pageInfo = array (
            "sex" => $output['sex'],
            "year" => $output['year'],
            "mount" => $output['mounth'],
            "day" => $output['day'],

            "username" => $output['username'],
            "fullname" => $output['fullname'],
            "location" => $output['location'],
            "status" => $output['status'],
            "fb_page" => $output['fb_bage'],
            "instagram_page" => $output['instagram_page'],
            "my_page" => $output['my_page'],
            "verfy" => $output['verfy'],

            "lowPhotoUrl" => $output['lowPhotoUrl'],
            "bigPhotoUlt" => $output['bigPhotoUrl'],
            "normalPhotoUrl" => $output['normalPhotoUrl'],
            "normalCoverUrl" => $output['normalCoverUrl'],
            "originPhotoUrl" => $output['originPhotoUrl'],
            "coverPosition" => $output['coverPosition'],

            "allowComments" => $output['allowComments'],
            "allowPPhotosComments" => $output['allowComments'],
            "allowVideoComments" => $output['allowVideoComments'],
            "allowMessages" => $output['allowMessages'],
            "postsCount" => $output['postsCount'],
            "videosCount" => $output['videosCount'],
            "giftsCount" => $output['giftsCount'],
            "friendsCount" => $output['friendsCount'],
            "allowShowMyInfo" => $output['allowShowMyInfo'],
            "allowShowMyVideos" => $output['allowShowMyVideos'],
            "allowShowMyFriends" => $output['allowShowMyFriends'],
            "allowShowMyPhotos" => $output['allowShowMyPhotos'],
            "allowShowMyGifts" => $output['allowShowMyGifts'],

            "follower" => $output['follower'],
            "inBlackList" => $output['inBlackList'],
            "follow" => $output['follow'],
            "friend" => $output['friend'],
            "blocked" => $output['blocked'],
            "lastAuthorizeTimeAgo" => $output['lastAuthorizeTimeAgo'],
            "online" => $output['online'],
        );
    }

    /**
     * @event photo.construct 
     */
    function doPhotoConstruct(UXEvent $e = null, )
    {
        Element::loadContentAsync($e->sender, $pageInfo['lowPhotoUrl'], function () use ($e, $event) {});
    }
}
```

**P.S.** *Я только начал изучать ООП, так что скорее всего я просто туплю*

Comment: сделайте ее просто членом класса. будет у вас `$this->pageInfo`. зы: не утомились копировать поля массива по одному? нельзя просто взять `$output` целиком, или просто перечислить копируемые поля, и воспользоваться какой-нибудь функцией для работы с массивами?

Comment: @teran, нельзя просто взять ```$output``` целиком, т.к. это своеобразный буффер.

Comment: `$page_info = array_intersect_key($output, array_flip([тут список необходимых ключей]))';`

Comment: @splash58, что это такое, ещё и не работающее

Comment: @teran, при обращении к массиву ```$this->$pageInfo['username']``` _или любая другая ячейка_, возвращает весь массив

Comment: У вас нарушен принцип единой ответственности. У вас объект получает данные, формирует некий массив, а потом еще загружает вторым методом некий контент. Выделите в отдельный класс получение данных, не исключено что в будушем вы будете использовать не курл, например, а читать из файла или брать из базы данных.  Для $output я бы завел отдельную модель, данные в которую можно было бы закинуть через денормализатор, например. Ну и отдельный класс с свойством $output , в котором бы и было обращение как к свойству, что справедливо заметил @teran

Comment: @leonid_tosterovski Интересно даже, что у вас не работает? - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/052b724a4ab778ec7f5a1329dda9349e06ce39e2

Comment: @splash58 кроме нормальных данных в массиве оказывается ещё много всякого шклака. писать в ручную гораздо удобнее)

Comment: @teran ничего не понятно, но очень интересно

Answer (score 0):

почему метод **doConstruct** ничего не позвращает? 
Верните в doConstruct массив :

```
return pageInfo;
```

а в методе **doPhotoConstruct** используйте:
 `$this->doConstruct()`

Comment: Ничего не возвращает потому что не должен

Comment: @leonid_tosterovski тогда нужно определить массива в области видимости класса , а методе "doConstruct" обращаться к нему через $this->pageInfo. Но у чтите что он будет пустой пока не вызовите метод "doConstruct"